High-level logic to build SQL query
I've built an SQL query but didn't get expecting result. Looks like the luck of knowledge/experience doesn't allow me to understand where I went wrong.
Here is my task:
For users that have booked at least 2  trips with a hotel discount, it is possible to calculate their average hotel discount, and maximum hotel discount. write a solution to find users whose maximum hotel discount is strictly greater than the max average discount across all users.
Be careful not to include canceled trips.
Think about what the max average across all users means. Each user has an average hotel discount, these user averages are a collection of numbers, and any collection of numbers has a max.
Expected column names: user_id
My solution:
-- to find users with the max discount who has at least 2 not cancelled trips
WITH max_discounts_cte AS (
    SELECT user_id, MAX(hotel_discount_amount) as max_discount
    FROM sessions
    WHERE cancellation = FALSE AND hotel_discount_amount IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING COUNT(trip_id) >= 2
),
-- calculating avg of the max discount across all users
avg_max_discount_cte AS (
    SELECT AVG(max_discount) as avg_max_discount
    FROM max_discounts_cte
)
-- fetching users with max discount greater than the avg max discount across all users
SELECT user_id
FROM max_discounts_cte
WHERE max_discount > (SELECT avg_max_discount FROM avg_max_discount_cte)

I want to confirm if my high-level logic is correct.
here is the expected output

...greater than the max average discount across all users -> your query is only considering users having at least 2 bookings, not all users. That being said, please provide some input and expected outputs, else its more guessing than anything else. For example, should a booking without a discount be considered in the average (discount=0%) or not..

"For users that have booked at least 2 trips with a hotel discount, it is possible to calculate their average hotel discount..." That's a strange caveat, because you can calculate the average with just one trip as well.

@JGH Please see the updated task description and expected output.

You've provided expected output, but no input.
